# What is the R code to input the following file(txt format)? The file has 3 columns and is tab separated with special german symbols

Tags: r

```
Kreisschlüssel  Landkreis / Kreisfreie Stadt    Wert
5334    Aachen, Städteregion    10,0
7131    Ahrweiler, Landkreis    4,5
9771    Aichach-Friedberg, Landkreis    3,2
8425    Alb-Donau-Kreis 3,2
16077   Altenburger Land, Landkreis 13,6
7132    Altenkirchen (Westerwald), Landkreis    6,1
15081   Altmarkkreis Salzwedel  10,3
9171    Altötting, Landkreis    4,0
7331    Alzey-Worms, Landkreis  5,0
9361    Amberg, Kreisfreie Stadt    6,8
9371    Amberg-Sulzbach, Landkreis  4,0
3451    Ammerland, Landkreis    5,4
15082   Anhalt-Bitterfeld, Landkreis    13,1
9561    Ansbach, Kreisfreie Stadt   4,7
9571    Ansbach, Landkreis  3,3
9661    Aschaffenburg, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,6
9671    Aschaffenburg, Landkreis    3,3
9761    Augsburg, Kreisfreie Stadt  7,8
9772    Augsburg, Landkreis 3,5
3452    Aurich, Landkreis   8,6
7332    Bad Dürkheim, Landkreis 4,5
9672    Bad Kissingen, Landkreis    4,8
7133    Bad Kreuznach, Landkreis    7,3
9173    Bad Tölz-Wolfratshausen, Landkreis  3,1
8211    Baden-Baden, Stadtkreis 6,6
9461    Bamberg, Kreisfreie Stadt   5,6
9471    Bamberg, Landkreis  3,3
12060   Barnim, Landkreis   11,5
14625   Bautzen, Landkreis  11,5
9462    Bayreuth, Kreisfreie Stadt  7,0
9472    Bayreuth, Landkreis 4,3
9172    Berchtesgadener Land, Landkreis 4,1
6431    Bergstraße, Landkreis   5,4
11000   Berlin, Stadtstaat  15,5
7231    Bernkastel-Wittlich, Landkreis  3,9
8426    Biberach, Landkreis 2,8
5711    Bielefeld, Kreisfreie Stadt 10,4
7134    Birkenfeld, Landkreis   7,2
8115    Böblingen, Landkreis    4,3
5911    Bochum, Kreisfreie Stadt    10,9
8435    Bodenseekreis   3,5
5314    Bonn, Kreisfreie Stadt  7,2
15083   Börde, Landkreis    8,8
5554    Borken, Kreis   4,6
5512    Bottrop, Kreisfreie Stadt   9,4
12051   Brandenburg an der Havel, Kreisfreie Stadt  15,7
3101    Braunschweig, Kreisfreie Stadt  8,9
8315    Breisgau-Hochschwarzwald, Landkreis 3,9
4011    Bremen, Kreisfreie Stadt    11,6
4012    Bremerhaven, Kreisfreie Stadt   17,8
15084   Burgenlandkreis 14,7
8235    Calw, Landkreis 4,3
3351    Celle, Landkreis    9,1
9372    Cham, Landkreis 3,6
14511   Chemnitz, Kreisfreie Stadt  12,8
3453    Cloppenburg, Landkreis  6,0
9463    Coburg, Kreisfreie Stadt    7,5
9473    Coburg, Landkreis   4,7
7135    Cochem-Zell, Landkreis  4,4
5558    Coesfeld, Kreis 3,5
12052   Cottbus, Kreisfreie Stadt   14,4
3352    Cuxhaven, Landkreis 7,0
9174    Dachau, Landkreis   3,0
12061   Dahme-Spreewald, Landkreis  8,5
6411    Darmstadt, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,8
6432    Darmstadt-Dieburg, Landkreis    5,6
9271    Deggendorf, Landkreis   4,1
3401    Delmenhorst, Kreisfreie Stadt   11,3
15001   Dessau-Roßlau, Kreisfreie Stadt 13,6
3251    Diepholz, Landkreis 5,0
9773    Dillingen a.d.Donau, Landkreis  3,1
9279    Dingolfing-Landau, Landkreis    3,1
1051    Dithmarschen, Kreis 9,5
9779    Donau-Ries, Landkreis   2,6
7333    Donnersbergkreis    5,9
5913    Dortmund, Kreisfreie Stadt  14,1
14612   Dresden, Kreisfreie Stadt   11,1
5112    Duisburg, Kreisfreie Stadt  14,5
5358    Düren, Kreis    8,8
5111    Düsseldorf, Kreisfreie Stadt    10,0
9175    Ebersberg, Landkreis    2,8
16061   Eichsfeld, Landkreis    7,8
9176    Eichstätt, Landkreis    1,6
7232    Eifelkreis Bitburg-Prüm 3,3
16056   Eisenach, Kreisfreie Stadt  10,2
12062   Elbe-Elster, Landkreis  15,4
3402    Emden, Kreisfreie Stadt 10,8
8316    Emmendingen, Landkreis  3,6
3454    Emsland, Landkreis  4,1
5954    Ennepe-Ruhr-Kreis   8,1
8236    Enzkreis    3,3
9177    Erding, Landkreis   2,4
16051   Erfurt, Kreisfreie Stadt    11,3
9562    Erlangen, Kreisfreie Stadt  4,2
9572    Erlangen-Höchstadt, Landkreis   2,6
14521   Erzgebirgskreis 10,6
5113    Essen, Kreisfreie Stadt 13,3
8116    Esslingen, Landkreis    4,5
5366    Euskirchen, Kreis   7,1
1001    Flensburg, Kreisfreie Stadt 13,3
9474    Forchheim, Landkreis    3,5
7311    Frankenthal (Pfalz), Kreisfreie Stadt   8,1
12053   Frankfurt (Oder), Kreisfreie Stadt  15,2
6412    Frankfurt am Main, Kreisfreie Stadt 8,4
8311    Freiburg im Breisgau, Stadtkreis    6,7
9178    Freising, Landkreis 2,4
8237    Freudenstadt, Landkreis 4,1
9272    Freyung-Grafenau, Landkreis 4,9
3455    Friesland, Landkreis    7,2
6631    Fulda, Landkreis    4,5
9179    Fürstenfeldbruck, Landkreis 3,8
9563    Fürth, Kreisfreie Stadt 7,5
9573    Fürth, Landkreis    3,6
9180    Garmisch-Partenkirchen, Landkreis   4,4
5513    Gelsenkirchen, Kreisfreie Stadt 15,7
16052   Gera, Kreisfreie Stadt  13,7
7334    Germersheim, Landkreis  5,0
6531    Gießen, Landkreis   7,9
3151    Gifhorn, Landkreis  6,5
8117    Göppingen, Landkreis    4,9
14626   Görlitz, Landkreis  14,3
3153    Goslar, Landkreis   10,5
16067   Gotha, Landkreis    9,0
3152    Göttingen, Landkreis    7,6
3456    Grafschaft Bentheim, Landkreis  5,1
16076   Greiz, Landkreis    10,2
6433    Groß-Gerau, Landkreis   6,1
9774    Günzburg, Landkreis 3,2
5754    Gütersloh, Kreis    5,2
5914    Hagen, Kreisfreie Stadt 11,4
15002   Halle (Saale), Kreisfreie Stadt 13,0
2000    Hamburg, Freie und Hansestadt, Stadtstaat   9,0
3252    Hameln-Pyrmont, Landkreis   9,2
5915    Hamm, Kreisfreie Stadt  11,3
3241    Hannover, Region    9,6
3353    Harburg, Landkreis  5,6
15085   Harz, Landkreis 11,6
9674    Haßberge, Landkreis 3,8
12063   Havelland, Landkreis    10,4
8221    Heidelberg, Stadtkreis  5,8
8135    Heidenheim, Landkreis   5,7
8125    Heilbronn, Landkreis    4,1
8121    Heilbronn, Stadtkreis   6,8
5370    Heinsberg, Kreis    8,4
3154    Helmstedt, Landkreis    8,8
5758    Herford, Kreis  6,8
5916    Herne, Kreisfreie Stadt 14,1
6632    Hersfeld-Rotenburg, Landkreis   5,5
1053    Herzogtum Lauenburg, Kreis  7,0
16069   Hildburghausen, Landkreis   6,6
3254    Hildesheim, Landkreis   9,0
5958    Hochsauerlandkreis  5,6
6434    Hochtaunuskreis 4,5
9464    Hof, Kreisfreie Stadt   7,9
9475    Hof, Landkreis  5,2
8126    Hohenlohekreis  3,2
3255    Holzminden, Landkreis   9,1
5762    Höxter, Kreis   6,1
16070   Ilm-Kreis   10,1
9161    Ingolstadt, Kreisfreie Stadt    4,2
16053   Jena, Kreisfreie Stadt  7,8
15086   Jerichower Land, Landkreis  10,8
7312    Kaiserslautern, Kreisfreie Stadt    11,6
7335    Kaiserslautern, Landkreis   6,0
8215    Karlsruhe, Landkreis    3,6
8212    Karlsruhe, Stadtkreis   6,4
6611    Kassel, Kreisfreie Stadt    11,4
6633    Kassel, Landkreis   5,6
9762    Kaufbeuren, Kreisfreie Stadt    6,7
9273    Kelheim, Landkreis  3,2
9763    Kempten (Allgäu), Kreisfreie Stadt  5,0
1002    Kiel, Landeshauptstadt, Kreisfreie Stadt    12,3
9675    Kitzingen, Landkreis    3,7
5154    Kleve, Kreis    5,8
7111    Koblenz, Kreisfreie Stadt   7,4
5315    Köln, Kreisfreie Stadt  10,6
8335    Konstanz, Landkreis 4,9
5114    Krefeld, Kreisfreie Stadt   11,7
9476    Kronach, Landkreis  4,7
9477    Kulmbach, Landkreis 5,6
7336    Kusel, Landkreis    5,8
16065   Kyffhäuserkreis 14,7
6532    Lahn-Dill-Kreis 6,7
7313    Landau in der Pfalz, Kreisfreie Stadt   5,4
9181    Landsberg am Lech, Landkreis    3,3
9261    Landshut, Kreisfreie Stadt  5,3
9274    Landshut, Landkreis 2,8
3457    Leer, Landkreis 8,1
14713   Leipzig, Kreisfreie Stadt   14,5
14729   Leipzig, Landkreis  11,7
5316    Leverkusen, Kreisfreie Stadt    8,6
9478    Lichtenfels, Landkreis  5,0
6533    Limburg-Weilburg, Landkreis 6,5
9776    Lindau (Bodensee), Landkreis    3,1
5766    Lippe, Kreis    8,2
8336    Lörrach, Landkreis  4,4
1003    Lübeck, Hansestadt, Kreisfreie Stadt    12,3
3354    Lüchow-Dannenberg, Landkreis    11,6
8118    Ludwigsburg, Landkreis  4,3
7314    Ludwigshafen am Rhein, Kreisfreie Stadt 10,5
3355    Lüneburg, Landkreis 7,1
15003   Magdeburg, Landeshauptstadt, Kreisfreie Stadt   12,5
6435    Main-Kinzig-Kreis   6,1
9677    Main-Spessart, Landkreis    2,9
8128    Main-Tauber-Kreis   4,0
6436    Main-Taunus-Kreis   5,1
7315    Mainz, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,6
7339    Mainz-Bingen, Landkreis 4,8
8222    Mannheim, Stadtkreis    7,2
15087   Mansfeld-Südharz, Landkreis 15,9
6534    Marburg-Biedenkopf, Landkreis   5,6
5962    Märkischer Kreis    7,5
12064   Märkisch-Oderland, Landkreis    12,3
7137    Mayen-Koblenz, Landkreis    5,6
14627   Meißen, Landkreis   11,4
9764    Memmingen, Kreisfreie Stadt 4,1
10042   Merzig-Wadern, Landkreis    5,4
5158    Mettmann, Kreis 7,4
9182    Miesbach, Landkreis 3,6
9676    Miltenberg, Landkreis   3,5
5770    Minden-Lübbecke, Kreis  6,8
14522   Mittelsachsen, Landkreis    10,2
5116    Mönchengladbach, Kreisfreie Stadt   12,3
9183    Mühldorf a.Inn, Landkreis   4,4
5117    Mülheim an der Ruhr, Kreisfreie Stadt   9,3
9162    München, Kreisfreie Stadt   5,8
9184    München, Landkreis  3,2
5515    Münster, Kreisfreie Stadt   6,5
8225    Neckar-Odenwald-Kreis   4,6
9185    Neuburg-Schrobenhausen, Landkreis   2,5
9373    Neumarkt i.d.OPf., Landkreis    2,4
1004    Neumünster, Kreisfreie Stadt    12,6
10043   Neunkirchen, Landkreis  7,7
9575    Neustadt a.d.Aisch-Bad Windsheim, Landkreis 3,0
9374    Neustadt a.d.Waldnaab, Landkreis    4,6
7316    Neustadt an der Weinstraße, Kreisfreie Stadt    6,7
9775    Neu-Ulm, Landkreis  3,5
7138    Neuwied, Landkreis  6,3
3256    Nienburg (Weser), Landkreis 6,7
1054    Nordfriesland, Kreis    8,4
16062   Nordhausen, Landkreis   11,8
14730   Nordsachsen, Landkreis  13,4
3155    Northeim, Landkreis 8,1
9564    Nürnberg, Kreisfreie Stadt  9,0
9574    Nürnberger Land, Landkreis  3,3
9780    Oberallgäu, Landkreis   3,4
5374    Oberbergischer Kreis    6,9
5119    Oberhausen, Kreisfreie Stadt    12,8
12065   Oberhavel, Landkreis    10,5
12066   Oberspreewald-Lausitz, Landkreis    16,9
6437    Odenwaldkreis   6,7
12067   Oder-Spree, Landkreis   11,1
6413    Offenbach am Main, Kreisfreie Stadt 12,1
6438    Offenbach, Landkreis    6,9
3403    Oldenburg (Oldenburg), Kreisfreie Stadt 9,5
3458    Oldenburg, Landkreis    5,2
5966    Olpe, Kreis 4,8
8317    Ortenaukreis    4,0
3404    Osnabrück, Kreisfreie Stadt 9,1
3459    Osnabrück, Landkreis    4,5
8136    Ostalbkreis 4,3
9777    Ostallgäu, Landkreis    3,3
3356    Osterholz, Landkreis    4,9
3156    Osterode am Harz, Landkreis 10,7
1055    Ostholstein, Kreis  7,9
12068   Ostprignitz-Ruppin, Landkreis   13,2
5774    Paderborn, Kreis    7,4
9262    Passau, Kreisfreie Stadt    6,7
9275    Passau, Landkreis   4,7
3157    Peine, Landkreis    7,2
9186    Pfaffenhofen a.d.Ilm, Landkreis 2,4
8231    Pforzheim, Stadtkreis   8,8
1056    Pinneberg, Kreis    6,4
7317    Pirmasens, Kreisfreie Stadt 14,8
1057    Plön, Kreis 7,0
12054   Potsdam, Kreisfreie Stadt   8,8
12069   Potsdam-Mittelmark, Landkreis   7,9
12070   Prignitz, Landkreis 16,2
8216    Rastatt, Landkreis  4,0
8436    Ravensburg, Landkreis   3,1
5562    Recklinghausen, Kreis   11,9
9276    Regen, Landkreis    4,6
9362    Regensburg, Kreisfreie Stadt    5,4
9375    Regensburg, Landkreis   2,6
5120    Remscheid, Kreisfreie Stadt 9,5
8119    Rems-Murr-Kreis 4,6
1058    Rendsburg-Eckernförde, Kreis    6,4
8415    Reutlingen, Landkreis   4,7
5362    Rhein-Erft-Kreis    8,5
6439    Rheingau-Taunus-Kreis   5,2
7140    Rhein-Hunsrück-Kreis    4,8
5378    Rheinisch-Bergischer Kreis  6,9
5162    Rhein-Kreis Neuss   7,0
7141    Rhein-Lahn-Kreis    4,8
8226    Rhein-Neckar-Kreis  4,3
7338    Rhein-Pfalz-Kreis   4,1
5382    Rhein-Sieg-Kreis    6,1
9673    Rhön-Grabfeld, Landkreis    3,7
9163    Rosenheim, Kreisfreie Stadt 5,6
9187    Rosenheim, Landkreis    3,2
3357    Rotenburg (Wümme), Landkreis    5,3
9576    Roth, Landkreis 3,1
9277    Rottal-Inn, Landkreis   3,8
8325    Rottweil, Landkreis 3,4
16074   Saale-Holzland-Kreis    8,6
15088   Saalekreis  11,3
16075   Saale-Orla-Kreis    8,4
16073   Saalfeld-Rudolstadt, Landkreis  9,5
10041   Saarbrücken, Stadtverband   10,3
10044   Saarlouis, Landkreis    6,2
10045   Saarpfalz-Kreis 6,0
14628   Sächsische Schweiz-Osterzgebirge, Landkreis 10,8
3102    Salzgitter, Kreisfreie Stadt    10,3
15089   Salzlandkreis   13,1
3257    Schaumburg, Landkreis   8,7
1059    Schleswig-Flensburg, Kreis  9,5
16066   Schmalkalden-Meiningen, Landkreis   7,6
9565    Schwabach, Kreisfreie Stadt 5,3
8127    Schwäbisch Hall, Landkreis  3,7
6634    Schwalm-Eder-Kreis  5,7
9376    Schwandorf, Landkreis   3,7
8326    Schwarzwald-Baar-Kreis  4,1
9662    Schweinfurt, Kreisfreie Stadt   7,2
9678    Schweinfurt, Landkreis  3,2
1060    Segeberg, Kreis 5,6
5970    Siegen-Wittgenstein, Kreis  6,4
8437    Sigmaringen, Landkreis  4,3
5974    Soest, Kreis    7,2
5122    Solingen, Kreisfreie Stadt  8,9
3358    Soltau-Fallingbostel, Landkreis 7,9
16068   Sömmerda, Landkreis 11,6
16072   Sonneberg, Landkreis    5,5
7318    Speyer, Kreisfreie Stadt    7,3
12071   Spree-Neiße, Landkreis  11,8
10046   St. Wendel, Landkreis   4,4
3359    Stade, Landkreis    7,2
9188    Starnberg, Landkreis    3,2
1061    Steinburg, Kreis    6,9
5566    Steinfurt, Kreis    5,0
15090   Stendal, Landkreis  15,4
1062    Stormarn, Kreis 4,7
9263    Straubing, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,3
9278    Straubing-Bogen, Landkreis  3,2
8111    Stuttgart, Stadtkreis   6,1
7337    Südliche Weinstraße, Landkreis  4,4
7340    Südwestpfalz, Landkreis 5,6
16054   Suhl, Kreisfreie Stadt  8,8
12072   Teltow-Fläming, Landkreis   8,9
9377    Tirschenreuth, Landkreis    5,4
9189    Traunstein, Landkreis   3,5
7211    Trier, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,4
7235    Trier-Saarburg, Landkreis   3,6
8416    Tübingen, Landkreis 3,9
8327    Tuttlingen, Landkreis   3,6
12073   Uckermark, Landkreis    18,3
3360    Uelzen, Landkreis   8,3
8421    Ulm, Stadtkreis 4,9
5978    Unna, Kreis 10,4
16064   Unstrut-Hainich-Kreis   12,7
9778    Unterallgäu, Landkreis  2,4
3460    Vechta, Landkreis   4,0
3361    Verden, Landkreis   6,1
5166    Viersen, Kreis  7,8
6535    Vogelsbergkreis 5,7
14523   Vogtlandkreis   10,6
7233    Vulkaneifel, Landkreis  4,9
6635    Waldeck-Frankenberg, Landkreis  5,7
8337    Waldshut, Landkreis 3,6
5570    Warendorf, Kreis    6,0
16063   Wartburgkreis   6,7
9363    Weiden i.d.OPf., Kreisfreie Stadt   8,9
9190    Weilheim-Schongau, Landkreis    3,1
16055   Weimar, Kreisfreie Stadt    11,0
16071   Weimarer-Land, Landkreis    8,4
9577    Weißenburg-Gunzenhausen, Landkreis  3,9
6636    Werra-Meißner-Kreis 7,6
5170    Wesel, Kreis    8,0
3461    Wesermarsch, Landkreis  8,3
7143    Westerwaldkreis 4,7
6440    Wetteraukreis   5,5
6414    Wiesbaden, Landeshauptstadt, Kreisfreie Stadt   8,2
3405    Wilhelmshaven, Kreisfreie Stadt 14,2
15091   Wittenberg, Landkreis   11,9
3462    Wittmund, Landkreis 7,8
3158    Wolfenbüttel, Landkreis 7,5
3103    Wolfsburg, Kreisfreie Stadt 6,4
7319    Worms, Kreisfreie Stadt 8,7
9479    Wunsiedel i.Fichtelgebirge, Landkreis   6,7
5124    Wuppertal, Kreisfreie Stadt 12,1
9663    Würzburg, Kreisfreie Stadt  5,5
9679    Würzburg, Landkreis 3,2
8417    Zollernalbkreis 4,8
7320    Zweibrücken, Kreisfreie Stadt   8,3
14524   Zwickau, Landkreis  10,5
```

Comment: 3 columns and 385 rows including the first row for headers.

Comment: Maybe this: `x <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "MyGermanCharacter")`

Comment: When i use unempl1 <- read.delim(file="path.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec=",",stringsAsFactors=F), it gives me following error-"Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 1"

Comment: Separator is tab and not german symbol. German symbols are present in some rows of a column which would require encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`x <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, check.names=FALSE, sep = "\t")`